# Will my iMac stay on if I use it's display in target display mode for a Mac mini?

Tags: imac, mac-mini, thunderbolt

I have the new iMac and need a Mac mini. Is it easy to switch the display back and forth or do I have to plug and unplug?

Also.. Will the Mac mini continue to run in headless mode when I'm using the display with the iMac?

I'd like to connect to it via Remote Desktop most of the time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can switch painlessly from one to the other using <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.

[Here's the Apple knowledge base article about that](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3924), you may find it interesting in order to understand exactly how the target display mode works.

However, I'm not sure you can connect via Remote Desktop without having a physical screen connected (except if you already upgraded to Lion, the "virtual screen" functionality should do the trick). Unfortunately, I can't try this at home as I don't have any Macs without internal display.

Comment: Yes, you can connect to the iMac using screen sharing and do stuff when it's in target display mode. I think it uses some kind of virtual display - you can even go into display settings and adjust the resolution.