# Thunderbolt Target Display Mode, iMac still running?

Tags: imac, thunderbolt

I'm considering getting an iMac to be an external display for my Air via the Thunderbolt cable. When you put the iMac into Target Display Mode is it still available as a headless computer without a display?

UPDATE: close question, but oposite [Will my iMac stay on if I use it's display in target display mode for a Mac mini?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21419/will-my-imac-stay-on-if-i-use-its-display-in-target-display-mode-for-a-mac-mini)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the iMac does stay on, I have the 2010 model. CMD + F2, (on your iMac), will allow you to swap back and forth between the two computers.

Comment: You can also look in the Apple Support Document: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3924

Comment: yes thanks! "Applications running on the 27-inch iMac computer remain open and running while it is in Target Display mode."

Comment: Glad we could help. I just ordered my Belkin cable yesterday, took me a while to figure this out as well.